# How to create Windows 8.1 with Bing installation media?

Tags: windows-8.1, bing

I've read somewhere that I can modify a Windows 8.1 Core image so that it could be installed as Windows 8.1 with Bing and activated with my Lenovo G50-70's BIOS key. It has something to do with this: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn613856.aspx)

But I can't make it out what should I do. Would someone please give me a detailed, step-by-step description of it?

Comment: The question and answer has figuratively saved my life. Thanks!

Comment: I hate Microsoft. Stop making different versions of Windows requiring different product keys that are the same product. Is anything you make user friendly? **If you wipe a machine with this operating system, take a backup first. Microsoft doesn't provide ISO for Windows 8.1 with Bing**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The US English install media for Windows 8.1 CoreConnected (aka “Windows with Bing”) have leaked and are [available on bittorrent](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/56755-Windows-8-1-with-Bing-AKA-CoreConnected-CCSL-and-ProfessionalStudent-OEM-images). Unfortunately, other langueges do not seem to be available (yet?).

Comment: So all I need to do is just make a flash drive with the installer, and install it like any other version?

Comment: @Matteussz I don’t think a flash drive would work given the size of current `install.wim`s…

Comment: Thanks, I was able to reinstall my OS with that, and it automatically activated.

Comment: Would this be okay considering I live in the UK?

Comment: @DanW The key will work, but you will get the en-US version…

Comment: Amazing, it worked. After all the nightmares with Windows 8.1 not accepting the key, I finally found out that I had the Bing edition, even though it's supposed to be 'very rare' (I have the latest Acer budget mass-market laptop, so it can't be THAT rare). Look forward to a bounty soon.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the Media Creation Tool from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media), run it, and then select "Windows 8.1 Single Language" which is the "with Bing" version.
It will then allow you to download this edition as an ISO or direct to flash drive.

Comment: No, "Windows 8.1 Single Language" is not the "with Bing".

Comment: From my understanding, "Windows 8.1 with Bing" product keys won't work on regular Windows 8.1 ISOs. With the "Single Language Edition" they will. [This](http://www.pcsteps.com/210-download-windows-8-1-isos-legally-free-microsoft/) page suggests this is so, but it may be wrong (I haven't tried it personally)

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work for me.