# How to activate Windows 8.1 with Bing Processor

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-activation

Apparently Windows 8.1 with Bing Processor is different than Windows 8.1. Where do I get an iso (from a legit source), or how can I activate?

Currently I have Windows 8.1 installed and it does not accept  my Windows 8.1 with Bing Processor key...

Comment: I take it there is no label on the PC that gives you the key?  Where did you get the Win8.1 install image you are using?  Is it possibly an OEM version from a different manufacturer?

Comment: Nope. HP 110-430 has no sticker. I extracted it in bash with a command

Comment: Windows 8.1 with Bing ISOs are not nor have they ever been publicly available.

Comment: if you have trouble finding a link, give me a place to upload the ISO you need

Comment: Not a perfect answer but: https://superuser.com/questions/857065/how-to-create-windows-8-1-with-bing-installation-media?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8.1 Core and Windows 8.1 with Bing are 2 different editions with 2 different product key sets. So you can't use a key for the Bing edition on normal Window 8.1.

Download the correct Bing ISOs and reinstall Windows 8.1.

Google for those names to find DL links:

**32Bit:** `X19-57134_SW_DVD9_NTRL_Win_with_Bing_8.1_32BIT_English_OEM.img`
**64Bit:** `X19-57272_SW_DVD9_NTRL_Win_with_Bing_8.1_64BIT_English_OEM.img`